# Why my tests is taking too long to execute?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

PASS  src/components/Greet/Greet.spec.tsx (29.13 s)
PASS  src/components/Greet/Greet.test.tsx (35.275 s)

Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
Tests:       4 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        100.769 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.

I have tried using only() in the Greet.test.tsx file but looks like it is also not working !

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Greet } from "./Greet";

describe.only("Greet", () => {
  test("renders ok", () => {
    render(<Greet />);
    const textElement = screen.getByText(/hello/i);
    expect(textElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  test("renders a name", () => {
    render(<Greet name="tanmoy" />);
    const textElem = screen.getByText(/hello tanmoy/i);
    expect(textElem).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you show your Greet component?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.